# For what values of $z\in \Bbb C$ does $\sqrt{z^2}=z$ hold?

Tags: complex-analysis

> For what values of $z\in \Bbb C$ does $\sqrt{z^2}=z$ hold?

Is this question just asking whether there is a solution for $|z|=z$? I definitely know nonnegative real numbers work. I don't think it works with imaginary numbers, am I right?

Comment: how do you define $\sqrt{z}$ for $z\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: I assume you meant $\sqrt{z^2}$, because $(\sqrt z)^2=z$ (i.e. how I'd, reluctantly, read $\sqrt z^2$) is always true. $\sqrt{z^2}=\lvert z\rvert$ is an indentity which holds only for real numbers. Whatever definition of $\sqrt z$ you give for $z\in \Bbb C$ (I could guess yours, but what good does it do for anyone?), $\sqrt{z^2}=\lvert z\rvert$ never holds for $z\notin\Bbb R$. Therefore, the question *isn't* asking you to solve $\lvert z\rvert=z$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I defined $\sqrt{z}$ to be $r^{1/2}(cos\frac{\theta}{2}+isin\frac{\theta}{2})$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. So I guess I should analyze the radius and argument of the complex numbers to find equality?

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud here but since $z^{2}=r^{2}(cos2\theta + isin2\theta)$, then by the definition of $\sqrt{z}$, isn't  $\sqrt{z^{2}}=z$ true for all complex numbers $z$? Edit: Maybe I am wrong due to branch of argument...

Answer (score 0):

From the printing it is unclear whether you meant $\sqrt{z^2}$ or $\bigl(\sqrt{z}\bigr)^2$. In any case $\sqrt{t}$ is universally defined only when $t\geq0$, and is the unique real number $s\geq0$ satisfying $s^2=t$.

In all other cases the square root denoted by the surd $\sqrt{\cdot}$  is only a clearly defined function when some extra explanations are given. As an example, one defines the principal value $${\rm pv}\sqrt{\cdot}\ :\quad{\mathbb C}\setminus\{{\rm negative\ real\  axis}\}\to\{{\rm right\ half\ plane}\}$$
"in the usual way", and then omits the pv in the notation:
$$\sqrt{re^{i\phi}}:=\sqrt{r}\>e^{i\phi/2}\qquad(r>0, \ -\pi<\phi<\pi)\ .$$
For such $z=r e^{i\phi}$ the claim $\bigl(\sqrt{z}\bigr)^2=z$ is true. The other claim $\sqrt{z^2}=z$ holds when ${\rm Re} z>0$, because then $\sqrt{z^2}$ brings back $z$, and not $-z$.

Comment: I apologize for the messy notation! I meant $\sqrt{z^{2}}=z$. In the question, $\sqrt{z}$ is defined to be $r^{1/2}(cos \frac{\theta}{2}+isin \frac{\theta}{2})$. I am guessing the equality part fails due to the branch of argument?